# How to prove for an operator $L$ on a vector space $V$ that $Null(L^k)\subset$ $Null(L^{k+1})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

*This was a past exercise and I still struggle to understand why it is necessary to prove it. I could very well be doing it wrong too!* We have $L$, an operator (I'm assuming linear, but feel free to comment if it seems it would not be) on the vector space $V$. Prove that $Null(L^k)\subset Null(L^{k+1})$. What I've done so far: Let some $\textbf{x}\in Null(L^k)$. Then we have that $L^k(\textbf{x})=\textbf{0}$, or that $L_1(\textbf{x})L_2(\textbf{x})L_3(\textbf{x})...L_k(\textbf{x}) = \textbf{0}$. Now, since we're repeating the same operator $L$ we're okay just considering a single $\textbf{x}\in V$ at a time that will map to $\textbf{0}$, since $\textbf{x}$ is in the kernel of $L^k$. To me, it then seems obvious that it doesn't really matter how many $k$ times we repeat $L$ on $V$. Doing $L^{k+1}$ times won't add another $\textbf{x}$ into the kernel. This is how I'm understanding it for now...
I was told that the fact that the kernel of linear transformations on vector spaces always contains the zero vector was important. But I still don't see how to prove this without just saying, "Hey, it's obvious right?" Again, maybe I'm completely missing the point.

Comment: You need to show that if $L^{k}(x)=0$, then $L^{k+1}(x)=0$, and this follows from $L^{k+1}(x)=L(L^{k}(x))=L(0)=0$.

Comment: @user84413 Ah.. so you're saying that the $L(\textbf{x})$ terms are all nested within each other.. That's something I was thinking about incorrectly. Thank you. It's still pretty trivial, just not in the way I thought then..